# datatype : 'jsonstring' is ignoring totalpages and totalrecord in Jqgird version 5.2.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have recently upgraded my jqgrid from version 3 to 5.2.1,
While doing so I faced unique problem while returning data from server side.

What I want, is to send only 80 record from server side, with total records of 280, page=1 and totalpage=4, but my jqgrid always show page 1 of 1 and displaying View 1 - 80 of 80 records, and rownum is 80.

It should display 1-80 from 280 and page 1 of 4.

Seems like my jqgrid ignoring the totalpages and totalrrecords.

Here is my jqgrid code:

```
jQuery("#tradeList").jqGrid(
{
jsonReader : {
        id : "0"
    },
    url : 'getDetailAgingReportInternal.go',
    datatype : 'jsonstring',
    mtype : 'POST',
    datastr : '{"page":' + data.page + ',"total":'
            + data.totalPages + ',"records":' + data.total
            + ',"rows": ' + data.rowData + '}',
    colModel : data.colModel,
    pager : '#pagerTrade',
    rowNum : data.records,
    rowList : [ 80, 160, 240 ],
    viewrecords : true,
    height: "350",
    width : "auto",
    viewsortcols : [ true, 'vertical', true ],
    multiselect : data.multiselect,
    multiboxonly: true,
    onPaging : function(pgButton) {
        var pageNo = getPageNo("tradeList");
        var rowCount = getRowCount("tradeList");

        loadDetailAgingReport(1, postData.bucketType, postData.mode, postData.modeType, '', '', postData.entity, 
                            '', postData.entityId, postData.statusTypeId, postData.tradeTypeIdJson, postData.isOTC, 
                            pageNo, rowCount, '', false, false);

        return 'stop';
    },
    onSortCol : function(index, columnIndex, sortOrder) {
        //alert("index:"+index+", columnIndex:" +columnIndex + ", sortOrder:" +sortOrder);
        var colSort = {};
        colSort.index = getColumnIndex("tradeList", columnIndex);
        colSort.direction = sortOrder;
        var colSortList = [ colSort ];
        var pageNo = getPageNo("tradeList");
        var rowCount = getRowCount("tradeList");

        loadDetailAgingReport(1, postData.bucketType, postData.mode, postData.modeType, postData.colHeader, postData.statusType, postData.entity, 
                postData.colName, postData.entityId, postData.statusTypeId, postData.tradeTypeIdJson, postData.isOTC, 
                pageNo, rowCount, colSortList, false, false);

        return 'stop';
    },
gridComplete:function(){

}
});
```

I am calling ajax call first and then sending values to create jqgrid using datatype as jsonstring.
Can anybody suggest anything will on this.

Hi tony,
since data is the actual response of my server side i did something like this.
but seems like it is not working. I don't want to call ajax hence i directly used addJSONData. I search on google but all are using ajax call. Is there any other way to write datatype as a function.

```
datatype : function(data) {
                                var thegrid = this;//jQuery("#plist")[0];
                                thegrid.addJSONData(data.rowData);
                            },
```

data is json string receive from server which contain page,records,taotaPages,colMode,rows etc.

can you please suggest any way.

Comment: With little exceptions jsonstring an local datatypes are equal. When this is on the grid ignores the the page and etc parameters and count these depending on the builded data array which will be sused in the future. After jsonstring tha datatype automatically is set to local. So my question is Why do you need 80 records localy, but want to display another number of records?  What is the goal?

Comment: I have total 280 records but i want to display 80 per page, so that when i click on next button it should display 81 to 160 records out of 280.This works fine in older version where i define datastr and it reads value sent by server, but newer version ignores it any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use datatype json and configure the jsonReader to get data direct from the server. Upgrage from 3.x to 5.x is not easy. If you have difficulty with json config, please let me know

Comment: Hi Tony, if i change datatype as json then i have to make lot of changes in code which i don't want to perform. I am upgrading in order to get Frozen column functionality which 3.x does not support. Can you tell me any stable version which can support Forzen and my mention functionality.

Comment: I have degraded my version to 5.0.2, Now it seems to work fine at first page, it is displaying 1-80 of 84(total records) and 1 of 2 pages,but when i click of next page it shows 81-84 of 4 (since out of 84, 4 record will display in next page) and page 2 of 1.Any suggestion.

Comment: One possible solution in this case is to use datatype as function. Please refer the [Guriddo jqGrid docs](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/basic-grid/#datatype-as-function) . The idea is to call addJSONData function with parameter not the string but the object. You can easy convert your JSON string to object using JSON.parse or the build in Guriddo jqGrid function $.grid.parse()

Comment: Hi Tony, in older version we don't have frozen column functionality so i manually use jquery freeze function it freezes column but the problem is , when u click on checkbox of jqgrid like first row or any rows it does not take value. I am using this function to get selected count jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selarrrow'); but it does not take any value , may be it is because of jquery effect. Can you give me some suggestion on it?

Comment: @SurajBhandari, your last comment does nothing to do with your initial question. To be clear - do you have resolved the datatype problem? If you have another question feel free to ask it as new one.

Comment: Please prepare a small example in jsfiddle with your original jsonstring and I will try to resolve your initial problem?